# jquery push into multidimensional array from loop

Tags: jquery, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create an array within a for loop, by doing the following:

```
var newArr = [];
for(var j=0; j < ChargeTypes.ChargeType.length; j++){
    var ChargeTypeId = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].ChargeTypeId;
    var Date = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].Date;
    var NoOfRoomsAvailable = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].NoOfRoomsAvailable;
    newArr.push({ChargeTypeId},{Date});
    newArr.push({ChargeTypeId},{NoOfRoomsAvailable});
};
alert( JSON.stringify(newArr) );
```

This is creating:

```
[
    {"ChargeTypeId":"1"},
    {"Date":"2017-12-28"},
    {"ChargeTypeId":"1"},
    {"NoOfRoomsAvailable":"0"},
    {"ChargeTypeId":"23"},
    {"Date":"2017-12-28"},
    {"ChargeTypeId":"23"},
    {"NoOfRoomsAvailable":"3"}
]
```

But what I'm hoping for is to get something like this:

```
[1] //ChargeTypeID
    {
        Date:"2017-12-28",
        NoOfRoomsAvailable:"0"
    },
[23] //ChargeTypeID
    {
        Date:"2017-12-28",
        NoOfRoomsAvailable:"3"
    }
```

I've tried using this:

```
newArr[ChargeTypeId].push("Date",Date);
newArr[ChargeTypeId].push("NoOfRoomsAvailable",NoOfRoomsAvailable);
```

But I get this error:

TypeError: newArr[ChargeTypeId] is undefined

I'm clearly missing something, and it's probably something small lol but if anyone could help me out, that would be fantastic.

Comment: edited answer, plz check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) simply adds a value to the end of a (flat) array. Passing multiple parameters to `push` does not introduce additional levels within the array. Likewise, array indices are purely numeric, and sequential, starting at 0. If you have custom, sparse IDs (which are also strings, in your case), you can't use them as indices to retrieve/store values in your array.

Instead, try something like this:

```
var newArr = [];

for(var j = 0; j < ChargeTypes.ChargeType.length; j++){
    var chargeType = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j];
    var chargeAttribute = chargeType.Charge[0]['@attributes'];
    var chargeDetails = {
        ChargeTypeId : chargeType.ChargeTypeId,
        Date : chargeAttribute.Date,
        NoOfRoomsAvailable : chargeAttribute.NoOfRoomsAvailable
    };

    newArr.push(chargeDetails);
};
```

Your results here will look similar to this, which is a typical JSON-like structure:

```
[
    {
        ChargeTypeId : "1",
        Date : "2017-12-28",
        NoOfRoomsAvailable : "0"
    },
    {
        ChargeTypeId : "23",
        Date : "2017-12-28",
        NoOfRoomsAvailable : "3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
var newArr = [];
for(var j=0; j < ChargeTypes.ChargeType.length; j++){
    var ChargeTypeId = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].ChargeTypeId;
    var Date = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].Date;
    var NoOfRoomsAvailable = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].NoOfRoomsAvailable;
    newArr[parseInt(ChargeTypeId)] = {
        "Date": Date,
        "NoOfRoomsAvailable": NoOfRoomsAvailable 
    };
};
```

Comment: I need the ChargeTypeId to be the key of the array item (either 1, or 23) :)

Comment: I'm getting this:

[null,{"Date":"2017-12-28","NoOfRoomsAvailable":"0"},null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,{"Date":"2017-12-28","NoOfRoomsAvailable":"3"}]

Comment: If you pushed array to a specific index, then in between elements will be undefined/null.

Comment: if you want you can take like this structure
{
      "1": {
        Date : "2017-12-28",
        NoOfRoomsAvailable : "0"
    },
    "23": {
        Date : "2017-12-28",
        NoOfRoomsAvailable : "3"
    }
}

Comment: Arrays in Javascript do not work this way. JS does not support associative arrays, you have to work with objects in JS. See nbrooks' or my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are facing is that JS does not support associative arrays the way that some other languages do. Instead, JS has objects and you will have to live with it. The best thing at this point that you can do is to create:

```
$obj = [
    {"ChargeTypeId":"1", "Date":"2017-12-28", "NoOfRoomsAvailable":"0"},
    {"ChargeTypeId":"23", "Date":"2017-12-28", "NoOfRoomsAvailable":"3"}
]
```

And then you can reference the ID's as `obj.ChargeTypeId`. This can be achieved as following:

```
var newArr = [];
for(var j=0; j < ChargeTypes.ChargeType.length; j++){
    var Date = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].Date;
    var NoOfRoomsAvailable = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].NoOfRoomsAvailable;
    newArr.push({ChargeTypeId,Date,NoOfRoomsAvailable});
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you have just need to create `new array` of `ChargeTypeId` to allow push. Because currently `newArr[ChargeTypeId]` not found so its giving you error. Add `newArr[ChargeTypeId] = [];` before push.

Try this one :

```
var newArr = [];
for(var j=0; j < ChargeTypes.ChargeType.length; j++){
    var ChargeTypeId = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].ChargeTypeId;
    var Date = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].Date;
    var NoOfRoomsAvailable = ChargeTypes.ChargeType[j].Charge[0]['@attributes'].NoOfRoomsAvailable;
    newArr[ChargeTypeId] = [];
    newArr.push({ChargeTypeId},{Date});
    newArr.push({ChargeTypeId},{NoOfRoomsAvailable});
};
alert( JSON.stringify(newArr) );
```